# SublimeText C++ build on Windows

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, c++14, sublimetext

I'm using SublimeText-3 on Winodws 7 to do C++ programming, trying to take advantage of the build feature.

I created a C+++.sublime-build file in which I point to the compiler I would like to use, the same used by Qt installation ("path": "C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin").

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++", "*.cpp"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.cpp, source.c++",
    "path": "C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin",
    "shell": true,
    "variants": [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["g++", " -std=c++1y", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "-static-libgcc", "-static-libstdc++", "*.cpp", "&", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I hit Ctrl+B I get the following error:
[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: First question: *is* `libwinpthread-1.dll` available on your computer (in a location the executable will search for it)?

Comment: `libwinpthread-1.dll` is in that path `C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin`. Which executable, the result of the compilation? I guess ST just builds when I hit Ctrl+B, so `libwinpthread-1.dll` is being requested by the compiler, isn't?

Comment: Maybe the path to the `dll` files are not properly set so that `g++` can not find it.